# Collapse Dataframe Pivot to Single Row

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a list of tuples that I need to be converted into a single dataframe row where the first tuple item is converted into a column and the second into the corresponding value. Here's what I tried:

The data:

```
[(0, 0.52776772063535005),
 (4, 0.18798097301734626),
 (6, 0.09831844955142259),
 (5, 0.059519666448517437),
 (3, 0.054459995937603152),
 (9, 0.052905323520468818)]
```

treating this data as `test`, I tried to convert to dataframe and then pivot but I can't get the data to get flattened out as one records.

```
test = pd.DataFrame.from_records(scores[0])
test.columns=['t1','t2']
   t1        t2
0   0  0.527768
1   4  0.187981
2   6  0.098318
3   5  0.059520
4   3  0.054460
5   9  0.052905
```

`test2 = test.pivot(index=None, columns='t1',values='t2')`

```
t1         0        3         4        5         6         9
0   0.527768      NaN       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
1        NaN      NaN  0.187981      NaN       NaN       NaN
2        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN  0.098318       NaN
3        NaN      NaN       NaN  0.05952       NaN       NaN
4        NaN  0.05446       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
5        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN       NaN  0.052905
```

Whereas what I want is it to be in one row:

```
 t1         0        3         4        5         6         9
    0   0.527768  0.05446  0.187981   0.05952  0.098318 0.052905
```

Is there a way I can collapse the pivot to just be one row instead of having my data across multiple indexes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can change your index to one single value

```
test.index=[0]*len(test)


test.pivot(index=None, columns='t1',values='t2')
Out[525]: 
t1         0        3         4        5         6         9
0   0.527768  0.05446  0.187981  0.05952  0.098318  0.052905
```

Or using `bfill`

```
test.pivot(index=None, columns='t1',values='t2').bfill().iloc[[0],:]
Out[532]: 
t1         0        3         4        5         6         9
0   0.527768  0.05446  0.187981  0.05952  0.098318  0.052905
```

Or we create your df from the data

```
pd.Series(dict(data)).to_frame().T
Out[555]: 
          0        3         4        5         6         9
0  0.527768  0.05446  0.187981  0.05952  0.098318  0.052905
```

Comment: @trystuff yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

you could alternatively set the index to `t1` and when displaying, transpose the data frame, optionally sorting the values by index if you need to. This way it is not necessary to pivot the values.

```
import pandas as pd
records = [
 (0, 0.52776772063535005),
 (4, 0.18798097301734626),
 (6, 0.09831844955142259),
 (5, 0.059519666448517437),
 (3, 0.054459995937603152),
 (9, 0.052905323520468818)
]
test = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records, columns=['t1', 't2'])
test = test.set_index('t1')
test = test.sort_index().transpose()

# prints out:

t1         0        3         4        5         6         9
t2  0.527768  0.05446  0.187981  0.05952  0.098318  0.052905
```